# How to correctly position android layout controls?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working in native Android Mobile Application but it's getting to difficult to me to find out how to postion the controls in the screen. I have the following mockup of how the final screen should look like:

[image]

An here it is the a screenshot of what I've tried, but with no luck:

[image]

and the my layout XML code is:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.clin.app.CustomDialogProfileActivity">
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="La Musa Gastropub"
    android:textSize="65px"
    android:id="@+id/TituloNegocio" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500px"
    android:layout_below="@id/TituloNegocio"
    android:id="@+id/mapa">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/mapa"
    android:id="@+id/addressLayout">


</RelativeLayout>

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/addressLayout"
    android:rowCount="3"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="true"
    android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    android:useDefaultMargins="true">

    <TextView

        android:text="53 Calle y 18 Avenida, Barrio Rio de Piedras"
        android:id="@+id/DireccionNegocio"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:textSize="45px" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/phone"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="12345678"
        android:id="@+id/TelefonoNegocio"
        android:textSize="45px"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:paddingStart="20pt"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/point"
        android:src="@drawable/checkin_point"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <TextView
        android:text="L. 80"
        android:id="@+id/DineroNegocio"
        android:textSize="55px"
        android:paddingStart="20pt"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/facebook"
        android:src="@drawable/fb_square"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="L. 80"
        android:id="@+id/DineroFacebook"
        android:paddingStart="20pt"
        android:textSize="55px"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/clins"
        android:src="@drawable/clins_icon"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2" />
</GridLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Please, tell me how could I achieve the same as the mockup?.**
You can use whatever layoutControl (LinearLayout, TableLayout, etc), I just decided to use GridLayout thinking that it was going to be easier but it was not.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are using way too many layouts....performance matters a lot..

Comment: @johnrao07 Thanks for the advice! I'll take it into account